# Selecting multiple notes in Guitar Pro 8

Tags: guitar-pro

In Guitar Pro 8 is it possible to select more than one note at the same time; i.e. random notes in different bars - to copy and paste into another instrument line?

Answer (score 1):

not random notes, but yeah, just highlight the notes and copy into the other instrument.

could you give more detail though on what you want?

if you want to omit notes to the new instrument just press "R" and that'll create a rest where that note is. as far as randomly generated notes, you'd need to export as midi, write some python script to delete random notes, and then reimport it but that i dont find would be worth the effort for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this isn't possible. Your best workaround is to copy everything and delete the stuff inbetween.